# AngularFire2 Email Verification

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using AngularFire2 to authenticate users with Firebase.

I am allowing the user to change their email address.

```
firebaseUser: firebase.User

firebaseUser.updateEmail(newEmail).catch((data) => {...
```

Now I would like to also be able to set the `emailVerification` to `false`.

```
 firebaseUser.emailVerified = false;
```

Does the `updateEmail` function automatically set it to false, or is it something I need to manually do? If so, how?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I just set up a password account and set emailVerified to true via the admin node.js sdk. I reloaded the user on the client and got emailVerified set to true. I then updated the email on that user, reloaded it. The emailVerified was reset to false automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Works for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, here's how I believe it works (I stand to be corrected)

[According to the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateEmail), when you update an email with a new email, here's what happens:

> "An email will be sent to the original email address (if it was set) that allows to revoke the email address change, in order to protect them from account hijacking."

Upon confirmation (here's the part I'm not certain), the new email is set as `emailVerified: false`, because well the email that was verified is gone.

Therefore, if you would wanna have this new email address verified, then please resend a verification for that too.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.